# Very Basic Logic Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Given a set $S=\{-1,0,-5,-4\}$.Then is the following proposition true?
$\forall x, (x>0 \implies x^2>0)$.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here... How are the set and this formula related? Are you asking whether "$\forall x \in S (x>0 \rightarrow x^2 >0)$" is true? If so, yes... It is true and I will be happy to extend this to an answer.

Comment: https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf p.17. Also it holds for all real numbers, not only for a subset of them.

Comment: Curiously none of the numbers in $S$ are positive, so the hypothesis $x \gt 0$ fails for each of them.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning.Yes x ∈ S.

Answer (score 2):

Since no element of $S$ is greater than zero, the implication is vacuously true.

$$\forall x\in S(x>0\to x^2>0) \iff \neg\exists x\in S(x>0\wedge x^2\not\gt 0)$$

There does not exist a counter example; of an element in $S$ which is both greater than zero but having a square not greater than zero.

---

Note that this is *also* (vacuously) true: $\forall x\in S(x>0\to x^2< -1)$